# django design model

Tags: django-models

I'm trying to design model in Django.

I want that App can link to many languages, and from admin site when I create new app be able to select more then one language.

```
class Language(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class App(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

    languages = ?
```

How should I write it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
languages = ManyToManyField(Language)
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield is the relevant part of the Django docs you may find useful